# Pandas (Excel): How to read full value with zeros in start?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tostring, leading-zero

Good day.
I have an Excel file with two columns. The first column contains 12 numbers. Some of them have leading zeros.
I tried to prescribe "dtype=str" when opening a file, but Pandas still remove zeros. And I need these zeros (as string of course). How to solve this problem?
[Excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zhb7eSYrYVbgqOroqVPakLtDdpdqS7fL/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
xl_file = 'tmp2.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(xl_file, dtype=str)
pd.set_option('display.max.rows', None, 'display.max.columns', None)
print(df)

Output:
        one   two
0    104501  1234
1   1106514  2345
2    124501  3456
3   2015515  4567
4  21765037  5678
5    307547  6789
```

But i need to save lead zeros just as they exists in Excel file:

```
            one     two
    0   000104501   1234
    1   0001106514  2345
    2   000124501   3456
    3   0002015515  4567
    4   00021765037 5678
    5   000307547   6789
```

Comment: pass dtype='object' instead of `str`

Comment: 'object' - not working for me. I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
df=pd.read_excel('1.xlsx', dtype='object')
```

O/P:

```
      col1
0      001
1      002
2      003
3  0049920
```

Comment: I have already tried this method. nothing changes. zeros disappear

Comment: Which pandas version are u using?

Comment: pandas==1.2.3  | today installed it

Answer (score 1):

I get it!
The problem was in "Excel cell template" which has tvelve zeros. But infact it was a string cell.
So, a made my template of zeros in code:

```
df_str = df['one']
for i in df_str:
    print('{0:0>12}'.format(i))
```

Comment: Good, you can use: `df['one'] = df['one'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>12}'.format(x))` too.

Comment: thank's. I'll try. Still afraid of lambda :)